# Glade : How to display a window in fullscreen size?

Tags: python, gtk, fullscreen, glade

I am writting an application in Python using Glade to build the user interface. I want to open a open a window in fullscreen when my application starts. I managed to display it full screen by modifying the python code :

```
class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def _init_(self)
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file("mygladefile.glade")
    self.window = self.builder.get_object('main_window')
    self.window.fullscreen()
```

Is there a way to set the fullscreen size directly on Glade ? I can not find the proper option to set to do it...

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but you could set the default width and height to 10000 by 10000. The actual size will be constrained by your monitor size.

Comment: Actually when I set the default width and heigth to 10000 by 1000, it is not constrained and I can only see a quarter of my application. If I set the width and height to the correct resolution in glade it works but weirdly enough, the function set_size_request does not seem to have any effect...